# Doing a find operation in graphql resolver with a list field

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I have a list that is being sent from my backend. I am trying to do a lookup using another datasource

```
Field: (request, _, { dataSources: { dataSource} }) => 
    dataSource.find({ id: request.ListField }),
```

I did try using a for each loop inside this like but I am getting nulls returned.

```
        Field: (request, _, { dataSources: { xDataSource} }) => { 
        const ids = request.ListField ;
        ListField .forEach(element => {
           return dataSource.find({ id: element })});
    },
```

The find method takes in a id and sends a get request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax `ListField .forEach(element =>...` is not right. It should be `ids.forEach(element =>...`